# Error: node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index.d.ts(159,60): error TS1005: ',' expected

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, npm-install

To solve an npm error in anular project, delete the node modules in the angular project, reinstall the npm modules and run ng serve, the follwing error occur. How can it be solved?

```
Error: node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index.d.ts(159,60): error TS1005: ','expected.
node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index.d.ts(159,61): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index.d.ts(169,64): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index.d.ts(169,65): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index.d.ts(186,46): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index.d.ts(186,52): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index.d.ts(186,54): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index.d.ts(195,44): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index.d.ts(195,50): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index.d.ts(300,60): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index.d.ts(300,61): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index.d.ts(310,64): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index.d.ts(310,65): error TS1005: ',' expected.
```

My **package.json - devDependencies**

`

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.1.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "6.1.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.16",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
    "@types/jquery": "~3.2.16",
    "@types/node": "6.14.10",
    "codelyzer": "^4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-sonarqube-unit-reporter": "0.0.23",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
    "merge-stream": "^1.0.1",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "requirejs": "^2.3.6",
    "sonar-scanner": "^3.1.0",
    "ts-mockito": "^2.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "5.20.1",
    "typescript": "2.9.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you're using TS of at least 2.8 
Check your typescript version using

```
tsc -v
```

If it's less than 2.8 upgrade it with following command.

```
npm install -g typescript@latest
```

Please let me know if this works.

Comment: I am using the typescript version 3.2.4 and I'm still getting the error... any other idea?
ERROR in node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index.d.ts(158,60): error TS1005: ',' expected.

Answer (score 1):

it's typescript compiler problem. just replace 'let' with 'var' then error disappear. but it is not a proper solution.

Comment: it might work, but i think a better solution would be to fix the ts compiler rather than using the historical `var` keyword

Comment: the error is in a dependency ( d3-dsv) in this case, so  are suggesting editing the library?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to update my d3 types dependency. In my package.json I now use:

```
    "@types/d3": "^7.1.0",
```

Then npm install. Previously I was using version 5.7.1, which gave that error.